# Как активировать проверку на роли в spring mvc + spring boot + spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, авторизация, spring-boot, spring-security

Нужно заблокировать доступ к некоторым роутам в зависимости от роли. Пересмотрел около 5-7 гайдов по Spring MVC Security, роуты `blog/{id}`, `blog/new` должны быть доступны только админу, однако у меня на эти роуты может заходить любой, даже не авторизованный пользователь.

Авторизация работает правильно, роли подтягиваются в объект `principal` - проверял отладкой. Пробовал и с `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`, и c `hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')` - оба варианта игнорируются.

Думаю, возможно где-то нужно что-то включить, чтобы `antMatchers().access()` работал?

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable();
     http
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/", "/blog", "/blog/{id}", "/author", "/account").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/blog/edit/{blogId}", "/blog/new").access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
         .and()
         .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
         .and()
            //form login, logout
```

**Так проверял наличие ролей у авторизованного пользователя:**

```
@GetMapping("/userInfo")
public String getUserInfo(Model model, Principal principal) {
    String userName = principal.getName();

    System.out.println("User name: " + userName);
    User loginUser = (User)((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal();
    String userInfo = WebUtils.toString(loginUser); // возвращает роли склеенные через запятую, в данном случае - ROLE_ADMIN
    System.out.println(userInfo);
    model.addAttribute("userInfo", userInfo);
    return "userInfoPage";
}
```

Тем не менее на защищённые роуты в моём случае может зайти любой, в т.ч. и не авторизованный пользователь, т.е. фильтры на роуты вообще не работают.

Comment: Не совсем понятно какие пути кому доступны.

Comment: @RomanC хочу сделать `"/blog/edit/{blogId}", "/blog/new"` доступными пользователям с ролью `ROLE_ADMIN`, остальные доступны всем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно переписать последовательность матчеров, так чтобы сначала проверялись роли которые защищают доступ к пользователям с ролью `ROLE_ADMIN` а потом уже давать доступ всем.

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable();
     http
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/blog/edit/**", "/blog/new").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
         .antMatchers("/", "/blog", "/blog/**", "/author", "/account").permitAll()
         .and()
         .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
         .and()
            //form login, logout
```