# При отключении анонимуса в Spring Security все url-ы автоматически выдают 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, usercontrol

Есть **Spring Boot** проект, где используется **Spring Security**.

Процесс авторизации идет через сессию и при успешной авторизации приложение сохраняет в `cookie` информацию. 
Для `/login` и `/logout` я сделал доступ url-ов как `permitAll`, а остальные url-ы расписал как **authenticated**.

Когда пользователь стучится в защищенные url-ы без авторизации пишет что работает *anonymousUser*. 
При отладке видно что **Spring Security** если не получает запрос от авторизованного пользователя, то автоматом подставляет *anonymousUser*.

Как решение в **Spring Security Configuration** я выключил в `http.build` анонимный доступ(`anonymous.disable()`), но таким образом все мои url-ы, в том числе и `/login` и `/logout` попадают под `403 Forbidden`.

**В чем дело и как можно решить проблему?**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    public static final String SESSION_ATTRIBUTE = "JSESSIONID";

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**")
                .antMatchers("configuration/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger*/**")
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*:[*]"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(1000L);
        return corsConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(cors -> corsConfiguration()).and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authentication/login", "/api/authentication/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/file/*", "/api/report/*", "/api/user/information/*").authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.7.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.7.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.7.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.7.2'

    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '9.4.1.jre16'

    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20220320'

    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.10'

    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как активировать проверку на роли в spring mvc + spring boot + spring security](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820692/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-spring-mvc-spring-boot-spring-security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если настроить `filterChain` подобным образом, то проблем с `amonymous` пользователем не будет:

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(cors -> corsConfiguration()).and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authentication/login", "/api/authentication/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: вы просто откатились и включили обратно `anonymous`

Comment: поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Вопрос, как Вы самми написали, появился после того как вы добавили `.anonymous().disable()` и закрыли вы его просто удалив данную строчку и соответственно откатив  конфигурацию к предыдущей версии (за исключением разрешения к `/api/**` которые на авторизацию и права никак не влияют) https://i.imgur.com/hTkg2UM.png

Answer (score 0):

Может я конечно с недосыпа не понимаю ничего, но тут вроде все банально.
Спринг делает ровно то, что у Вас написано:
Вы ему к этим страницам не разрешаете никого пускать - он и не пускает!

Просто разрешите доступ к старницам `/login`, `/logout` в `filterChain()`

```
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
.logout()
    .permitAll()
```

либо банально:

```
.antMatchers("/login", "/logout").permitAll()
```

**Итого весь метод:**

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(cors -> corsConfiguration()).and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true) // дополнил вашими правилами
                    .deleteCookies(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE) // дополнил вашими правилами
                  .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authentication/login", "/api/authentication/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/file/*", "/api/report/*", "/api/user/information/*").authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
```